# Can Installshiled msbuild task be used to build ism which produce msp as output?

Tags: msbuild, installshield, msbuild-task

I am using Msbuild installshield task to build ism which produces msi as output. Refer [Msbuild installshield task link](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield14helplib/MSBuild.htm)

Now Msp has to be build and i am doing it by opening installshield and [build patch].

Is there any commandline [so i can use it msbuild or in batch file] or msbuild installshield task is available to build ism [which produce msp]?

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the version of InstallShield you are using; you referenced an InstallShield 2008 help article, which is a version without this capability. The capability was added in InstallShield 2009 per the `PatchConfiguration` parameter documented in the IS2009 version of the [InstallShield MSBuild Task](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/MSBuild.htm) help article. See also the [command-line build parameters](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/ISCmdBldParam.htm) for `-patch_config`, also added in IS2009.

Comment: I am using Installshield 2010